# Mac low-level keyboard device corresponding to Linux /dev/input?

Tags: macos, keyboard, hid, iokit, darwin

What is the name of the low-level keyboard device in macOS (somewhere in Darwin / Mach / IOKit) that corresponds to `/dev/input` in Linux? (e.g. `/dev/input/event0`)

Context: I'm asking because want to 'map' the Mac device to a Docker container running Linux.

Comment: As a side note regarding your context remark: as far as I'm aware, Docker containers on macOS usually run in an independent Linux kernel running below a hypervisor called HyperKit. I don't know if each container gets its own VM, or if the container features are used on a single VM's Linux kernel. In any case, [HyperKit currently doesn't support USB device pass-through](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit/issues/149). Other virtualisation environments such as VirtualBox, VMWare Fusion and Parallels *do* support direct USB passthrough on Mac, in case that's an option for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such direct correspondence with a `/dev/` node on macOS. HID events are (eventually) processed in the `IOHIDSystem` class in the kernel and are transferred to user space into WindowServer via the `IOHIDUserClient`. Applications can also directly access aspects of a HID device directly via the IOHIDLib, which uses `IOHIDLibUserClient` to get kernel HID data.

macOS only uses `/dev/` nodes for a handful of device types, notably block devices (`diskXsY`, `rdiskXsY`), serial ports, and the traditional UNIX virtual devices such as `null`, `zero`, `random`, etc. There are also a few BSDisms, such as BPF. Almost everything else is handled only via IOKit.